# Migration from lodash 3 to lodash 4: what replaces the 'lodash/string/template'?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, lodash

We try to migrate one Backbone.js project from lodash "3.10.1" to latest lodash "4.17.21" and seems like 'lodash/string/template' was removed in version 4.

In our code we have something like:

```
import template from 'lodash/string/template';

export default _.extend(window.app, {
...
    template: (path, options) => template(someCustomMethod(path), options),
...
```

And with lodash 4 installed the bundler crashes with:

**Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'lodash/string/template'...**

In case I import it this way:

```
import { template } from 'lodash';
```

Then compilation passes but when you try to load the app then an error occurs:

**...Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_url_prefix')**

It comes from inside "Backbone.View" and seems related to lodash template.

Have someone stumbled upon such an issue? The Backbone.js version is 1.1.2, but I think it's not related - if I return back to lodash "3.10.1" then all works perfectly. Maybe the new lodash template version returns differently structured results?

Comment: If you update your Lodash dependency, I recommend updating Backbone itself as well. Lodash made a bunch of breaking changes. Underscore and Backbone adapted to those changes in order to keep everything compatible.

Comment: By the way, you could consider switching back to Underscore instead. I maintain it. Lodash has not seen any maintenance for two years.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want

```
import template from 'lodash/template';
```

and for the `_url_prefix` error it's impossible to say more without the full stack trace.